# WCF PerCall not firing Faulted event

Tags: c#, wcf

I am using `wsHttpBinding` with `InstanceContextMode.PerCall`. On the server side I need to detect if the client has properly received the `response`. If not I need to clear some stuff in the server side. For this I tried to use `OperationContext.Current.InstanceContext.Closed` and `OperationContext.Current.InstanceContext.Faulted`. `OperationContext.Current.InstanceContext.Closed` fires always but .Faulted event never fires no matter what I do (timeout the connection, close the client while still receiving the data, unplug the cable). Also `OperationContext.Current.InstanceContext.State` is always closed.

How can I detect that the client did not received the request ?
As an alternative solution I was thinking if I catch error on the client side, to call a cleanup method on the server side, but this may complicate things because the internet connection may be down for a while.

Comment: I do not think this is possible. The acknowledgement is always from server to client. If you need an acknowledgement from client to server, you have to do it by calling another web service.

Answer (score 0):

Channel events on the service side are fired when the client calls Close() successfully, you will not get channel events fired on the server side because of client faults and timeout until the moment the server replies, which is very stupid.

To solve your problem you have three solutions:

1- if the client is yours, use duplex to call a dummy method on the client then the channel will fire its events.

2- use reliable session (sessionfull binding + reliable session turned on) so you can set the "InactivityTimeout" which will fire when infra messages like KeepAlive messages are not coming anymore. I guess InactivityTimeout default is 10 minutes, while Windows KeepAlive frequency is 1 second, so you can set InactivityTimeout to 5 seconds for example.

3- use IIS hosting with one of the http bindings, so inside your operation create a loop that keeps checking "ClientDisconnectedToken.IsCancellationRequested" in "HttpContext.Current.Response" in "System.Web" namespace.